# Prevent unwanted back to previous page with a mouse right click with Firefox

Tags: firefox, right-click, navigation

when clicking on the right mouse button in a page, we've got this contextual popup:

[image]

But if you move to the right a little to reach immediately the ⬅ icon then you go back to the previous page, even without clicking a second time.

[And here is the screen video.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1sut7i4ut446kuy/right-click.mp4?dl=0)

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?
Is it a bug or a feature?

I have found [related issues](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1180792), but the mentioned fixes don't apply in my case.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 75.0

Comment: Hi, I will try to make the video.

Comment: @Furty Video added.

Comment: Hum, you are right, I tried with another mouse, and I have the same behaviour. So, it seems it is a "feature". You can't do it on windows?

Comment: I am using macOS Mojave, no mouse extension. Note, that I have the same behaviour in Firefox and Firefox developer edition. I don't' understand your question. "Why don't...": I want to deactivate a feature that happens when I want to, it has nothing to do with an action I want to do. To go back yes I use the back standart back button.

Comment: Any other extensions installed, common to both Firefox versions? You can try to go through all steps suggested by [Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems). If you press the normal back button in the Firefox GUI long with right mouse button, does it show history normally or also go back immediately when moving the mouse a little?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107392/discussion-between-coil-and-furty).

Comment: Hi, important update, it doesn't comes from Firefox but from the MacOS because I could reproduce the same behavior with another application.

Comment: Finally I found a similar issue on Askdifferent : https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/367395/67975

Answer (score 1):

*copied directly from my answer at  [Ask Different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62aKm.gif)*

This is expected behaviour & depends how long you hold your initial click for.

This is the same for any menu item on regular left click too. It is observed through the entire macOS.

1. Short click & the menu will wait for another distinct click.
2. Click & hold & it will trigger as soon as you let go.

If your mouse has a dodgy button, it may let go before you *think* you did, causing behaviour 2.

With behaviour 1, you can just take your time wandering around sub menus without having to click anything until you're completely ready. The menu will just wait for you.

As some appear to misinterpret this, here are two examples. The circle round the cursor is the click indicator, green is right, black is left…

**short click** - you can wander around the menu as you wish, even leave its bounds & return, it won't trigger until you click a second time, or click outside it to dismiss.

[image]

**long click/click & hold** - this will trigger as soon as you let go of the mouse button

[image]